Loading TTF of monaco-editor in Angular 17
I have installed ngx-monaco-editor-v2 in my Angular 17.3.3 app as specified in the instructions, i.e.:

npm install monaco-editor ngx-monaco-editor-v2 --save (current versions: 0.47.0 for monaco-editor, 17.0.1 for ngx-monaco-editor-v2)
add glob to assets in angular.json:

{
  "glob": "**/*",
  "input": "node_modules/monaco-editor",
  "output": "/assets/monaco/"
}

I then import it in app.config.ts (the default Angular app from ng new is standalone):
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    importProvidersFrom(MonacoEditorModule.forRoot())
  ],
};

This works, and I can use Monaco via the wrapper, like this (in my consumer component):

import Monaco in the standalone component imports, e.g.:

import { MonacoEditorModule } from 'ngx-monaco-editor-v2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterOutlet,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MonacoEditorModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css',
})



add editor options, e.g.:

public editorOptions = {
  theme: 'vs-light',
  language: 'markdown',
  wordWrap: 'on',
  // https://github.com/atularen/ngx-monaco-editor/issues/19
  automaticLayout: true,
};


in the component's template, place the editor:

<div id="editor">
  <ngx-monaco-editor
    [options]="editorOptions"
    formControlName="text"
    (onInit)="onEditorInit($event)"
    style="height: 100%"
  />
</div>

I can use onEditorInit to get a reference to the editor, which works:
public onEditorInit(editor: any) {
  this._editor = editor;
  editor.focus();
}

Now I would need to work with the editor reference, so rather than using any I would set the type to monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor. This requires importing monaco like import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor'.
As soon as I try this, I get this build error:
Application bundle generation failed. [6.012 seconds]

✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".ttf" files: node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/codicons/codicon/codicon.ttf
    node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/codicons/codicon/codicon.css:9:6:
      9 │   src: url(./codicon.ttf) format("truetype");

So the Angular's Webpack does not seem to be able to load the TTF font required by Monaco. I have tried to add a custom Webpack configuration, which means:

installing this loader to load TTF: npm install --save-dev font-awesome-loader.
adding a new webpack.config.js file to the root of my project, with this content:

export default (config, options) => {
  return {
    ...config,
    module: {
      ...config.module,
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ttf$/,
          use: ["font-awesome-loader"],
        },
      ],
    },
  };
};

Yet, no luck. I am still getting the same error. Could anyone suggest how to fix this load issue?

please share a stackblitz also with the issue happening for debugging!

Thank you, I tried with stackblitz but there it seems it is working. I then built a new app from scratch as a repro, with the same commands of the previous one, and it works too. This sounds rather suspect, as both the apps were created today from scratch, in the same machine and with the same Angular version, and even the same code copy-pasted from one to another. Should I be able to repro it or find any relevant difference I'll post more.

In dealing with a connected issue, I prepared a repro for it, and surprisingly the error of this post surfaced again. While it worked in the computer where I originally created the project, it came back when copying its source elsewhere and restoring packages with npm i. Yet, both machines have the same configuration and Angular and NodeJS versions. You should thus be able to repro it by using this repository.

The @angular-devkit/build-angular:application builder has a new option "loader" which you can define how different file types should be loaded.
In your angular.json, add this option to fix the issue.

Read this pull https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/26371 to learn more about this option.

Thank you this should solve my issue. I just moved to another Monaco wrapper which is more lightweight and does not seem to present this issue, but this still remains a good hint.

@Naftis, which Monaco wrapper did you switch to?

https://github.com/cisstech/nge
