Angular can't find ngx-monaco-editor
I'm using angular 17.1 with the angular monaco ngx project:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-monaco-editor-v2
I followed the directions, and no matter what when i compile, angular always throws the error: "'ngx-monaco-editor' is not a known element:".  I've tried multiple ways to import it and different libraries and ways to reference it but there seems to be disconnect.  Currently I have it setup exactly like in the demo.
ngx monaco error

Did you put it in the AppModule ?

I did, it's identical to the sample.

Ok, Can you show your component, HTML and ts, and also package.json ?

Maybe look at this, see if it helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78293918/loading-ttf-of-monaco-editor-in-angular-17

I tried this and I get past that error by using the reference within the component itself.  However I see a new error:

ERROR ReferenceError: window is not defined
at eval (C:\app\new\app\node_modules\ngx-monaco-editor-v2\fesm2022\ngx-monaco-editor-v2.mjs:37:9)
